# How to check if an input doesnt have a value and a session key exsists

Tags: javascript, jquery

So we are adding our tracking data (UTM) to hidden fields on a form, when someone lands on the page i create a sessionstorage item with the value of the utm so that it will follow them as they move around our site. I'm trying to add in a catch so when someone submits a form it will check if the input is empty if it is then it will check if the sessionstorage exsists and try and repopulate the input field

```
$('#contactUsBtn, #TAContactSubmit, #contactUsMinBtn').click(function () {

    if (!$('.contact-form-container #Source').val() && sessionStorage.getItem("utm_source") === null) {
        console.log('No value on input but has a session val');
    }

});
```

im assuming there is an easy way to achieve this and i'm missing it.

Comment: the condition is `!$('.contact-form-container #Source').val() && localStorage.getItem("utm_source") !== null`

Comment: in the description you mentioned you are using sessionStorage but in the code it is localStorage however what is the exact issue?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Ahh yer sorry that should be sessionStorage ive edited that now.

Comment: Keeping data on client side on which your validation is dependent is highly insecure as  anyone can modify your sessionStorage and your validation may go wrong so this in this case also you should follow server side validation by storing data on server side instead of client side

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar No this is just UTM data to pass into the form it doesnt have any validation as its only active if someone comes to the site via PPC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way. You first check weather the input has value or not. After that if the input doesn't have any value you check session storage.

```
  if ($('.contact-form-container #Source').val() == "") {
      if(sessionStorage.getItem('utm_source') != undefined || sessionStorage.getItem('utm_source') != null) {
          console.log('No value on input but has a session val');
      } else {
          console.log("No value in session too");
      }
  } else {
     console.log('Value on input');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With "===" you compare the value and type. 
you want to use !== null. the value of the session items should NOT be null, there for !== and not ===